# The element type 'List<dynamic>' cannot be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. I am getting dartlist_element_type_not_signable error,what should I do?

Tags: flutter

The element type 'List<dynamic>' cannot be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. I am getting dartlist_element_type_not_signable error, what should I do?

```
import 'package:calculator/button_values.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CalculatorScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalculatorScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CalculatorScreen> createState() => _CalculatorScreenState();
}

class _CalculatorScreenState extends State<CalculatorScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        child: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(19),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: const Text(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                      "0",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 49, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
            ),
          ),
            Wrap(
            children: [
              Btn.buttonValues.map((ese) => hello(ese)).toList();
            ]
              
            
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

   hello(value){
    return Text(value);
  }
}
```

What can i do about this problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hello` method returns a `dynamic`. Add the return type `Widget`:

```dart
Widget hello(String value) {
  return Text(value);
}
```

Notice how I also add the `String` type to the `value` parameter. Dart is a strongly typed language so you need to pay attention to type annotations. I recommend you to see these resources:

- https://dart.dev/language#important-concepts
- https://dart.dev/effective-dart/design#types
- https://dart.dev/language/functions